# How to disable/enable a plugin at a specific time

Tags: plugins, functions

Is there a hook that would allow me to disable and enable a specified plugin at a certain time?

For example, I would like to disable the wp contact form 7 plugin every Tuesday at 6 AM and enable it on Wednesday at 2 PM.

Is this feasible?

Thanks!

---

I guess I wasn't clear enough, but I only used Contact From 7 as an example. The plugin I want to disable is a random plugin, and I want to totally disable it and enable it based on a predefined time.

Comment: Do you actually want the plugin deactivated, or do you just want a form itself to be closed to submissions during this time? Those are two very different questions.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I guess I wasn't clear enough, but I only used Contact From 7 as an example. The plugin I want to disable is a random plugin, and I want to totally disable it and enable it based on a predefined time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [deactivate_plugins()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/deactivate_plugins) function to deactivate a plugin

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'deactivate_plugin_conditional_hook' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'twicedaily', 'deactivate_plugin_conditional_hook' );
}

add_action( 'deactivate_plugin_conditional_hook', 'deactivate_plugin_conditional_2345678999343434' );

function deactivate_plugin_conditional_2345678999343434() {
$plugin_path = 'plugin-folder/plugin-name.php';
    if ( is_plugin_active($plugin_path) ) {
    deactivate_plugins($plugin_path);    
    }
}
```

You can set custom event see here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

**Note: this is not tested code**

Comment: If the actual plugin itself is totally deactivated then the short code is going to appear in the content.

Comment: You can check if a plugin active with this function is_plugin_active($plugin_path), then can conditionally output short code

Comment: Not inside content you can’t.